TListBox, TFrame and mouse selection
This code actually works, except that when elements (Mainly TLabels with HitTest True) on Frame are clicked, the listbox1 item do not become highlighted (and ItemIndex is -1 ).
function TForm1.ShowUpdatedValues: Boolean;
Var Item: TListBoxItem;
    Frame: TMyDesignedFrame;
begin
     try
       ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
       ListBox1.Items.Clear;
       for q:=1 to 5 do begin
         Item:=TListBoxItem.Create(Self);
         with Item do begin
           Height:=100;
           Parent:=ListBox1;
         end;
         Frame:=TMyDesignedFrame.Create(Item);
         with Frame do begin
           Parent:=Item;
           // Here ...
           // OnMouseDown:=ListBox1MouseDown;
         end;
       end;
     finally
       ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
     end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var i:integer;
begin
     i := ListBox1.Items.IndexOfObject( ListBox1.ItemByPoint( x, y ) );
     FeedbackLabel.Text := i.ToString+'  x '+Trunc(x).ToString+'   y '+Trunc(y).ToString;
end;

Even uncommenting OnMouseDown:=ListBox1MouseDown no way to select the item, or having back the itemindex...
What I am missing ?
Thank you
